# RHEL 5.2 installing on ProLiant BL460c - hangs at 'now booting the kernel'

Tags: linux, redhat, installation, hp-proliant, ilo

As the title states, I have a problem.
This server and the installation disc are also on the other side of the world to me so...

So far, I have tried to start the install with the parameters: 
linux text noapic noacpi no=apic no=acpi

which results in the same hang. 
I have also disabled a PCI ethernet adapter, I am uneasy about disabling the onboard ethernet adapter I do not know if ILO uses this.

Anyone have any advice?
Much appreciated.

EDIT: full output after trying to begin the installation.

```
boot: linux text
Loading initrd.img..................
Loading vmlinuz.......
Uncompressing Linux...done.
Now booting the kernel

stays on this for hours
```

EDIT2: adding the 'mem=40960M' (server has 40 gigs of ram) parameter allows it to proceed but the following output directly after 'Now booting the kernal'

```
Memory: sized by int13 0e801h

initrd extends beyond end of memory (0x00ef2090 > 0x00000000)

disabling initrd

Console: 16 point font, 400 scans

Console: colour VGA+ 80x25, 1 virtual console (max 63)

pcibios_init : BIOS32 Service Directory Structure at 0x000ffee0

pcibios_init : BIOS32 Service Directory entry at 0xf0000
```

Comment: Try mem=1024M or something below 4GB. Is this a 64-bit OS or 32-bit? Please also provide hardware details.

Comment: If I use 1024M it continues without the error but stops at the same point after 'entry at 0xf000'. The OS is 32 bit, 40 gigs of RAM and 12 cores at 3067 MHz, hard drive is RAID 6 on SAN.

Answer (score 2):

Which generation of BL460c are you using? G5? G6? G7? That could be a factor if you're attempting to install RHEL 5.2 (circa 2008) on newer hardware. Do you have any option to use a newer version of the OS? RHEL 5.7 is available...

Where is the installation CD located? Is it mounted via the ILO? The BL460c series servers are [supported under RHEL 5](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/linux/supportmatrix/rhel/exceptions/rhel-exceptions.html), and you shouldn't need any special boot parameters.

Either way, the ILO is separate from the onboard ethernet, and you shouldn't need to disable any devices to complete the installation.

EDIT: The OP updated the server description. The lowest version of RHEL supported on the [HP ProLiant BL460c G7 is RHEL 5.5](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/linux/supportmatrix/rhel/exceptions/rhel-exceptions.html).

*The RHEL 5.2 you're trying to install will not work*.

Comment: This is G7, Unfortunately the installation has to be 5.2 (legacy fun). I believe the CD is physically inserted in the iLO enclousre and somehow linked to the server but I have limited access here. I have added additional information to my main post, adding the memory to the install lets it continue a little further but more errors occur. I am researching this now, if you have further advice it is very appreciated.

Comment: Yes, the G7 only supports RHEL 5.5 or greater. Your version 5.2 will not work.

Comment: Where is this information listed? I have been hunting around for awhile now but I am unable to find it, sorry.

Comment: Click the link in my answer or go here and look for the row referencing your server model, and look at the "Minimum Supported Red Hat Updates" column: http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/linux/supportmatrix/rhel/exceptions/rhel-exceptions.html#BL

Comment: thanks, this is very difficult now but at least it isn't my fault ;)

Comment: Actually it is quite easy. You install a supported version of RHEL and then run RHEL 5.2 in a virtual machine within that (using kvm or xen or rhev or vmware)

But please do check the cd for the reason given in the other answer.

Comment: If this was the answer, please mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Get someone to check the cd.

This line: "Memory: sized by int13 0e801h" looks too old to be RHEL5.2 and is probably the much older, pre-Fedora RH5.2 from the last century.